# Library to Record from Webcam Using Flash and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, webcam

Has anyone used any libraries to record from a webcam in the browser, and then use that to upload to YouTube? I think there are some Flash/JavaScript solutions, some I have found are ScriptCam (http://www.scriptcam.com/), jpegcam (http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/), nimbb (http://nimbb.com/), and Viddler (http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/articles/howto-record/).

Has anyone used any of these libraries, or can you recommend other libraries?

Comment: here is a working [online demo](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/Webcam/online_demo_Webcam.aspx) of capturing videos into a container in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube has an interface for webcam recordings and upload:

http://www.youtube.com/my_webcam

However, I read on your question that you are seeking a video hosting service that isn't necessarily YouTube.

I would recommend red5, they allow you to gain full control on both server side, and client side events

http://www.red5-recorder.com/demo.php